# Extracting arguments of an R function to use in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Arguments of `lm` function can be obtained by using:

```
args(lm)
```

**Output**

```
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
NULL
```

**Questions**

How to get:

```
lm (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)
```

with the description (Not complete help) of each Argument to be used in `Sweave` or `knitr`. Thanks

**Edited**

Using funExtract function provided by @Ananda, I'm very close to my desired result. Here is code of my `Rnw` file with output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Arguments for lm

<< label = funExtract, echo = TRUE, results = "hide", tidy = FALSE >>=
funExtract <- function(Function, section = "Usage") {
  A <- deparse(substitute(Function))
  x <- capture.output(tools:::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(help(A))))
  B <- grep("^_", x)                    ## section start lines
  x <- gsub("_\b", "", x, fixed = TRUE) ## remove "_\b"
  X <- rep(FALSE, length(x))
  X[B] <- 1
  out <- split(x, cumsum(X))
  out <- out[[which(sapply(out, function(x) 
    grepl(section, x[1], fixed = TRUE)))]]
  cat(out, sep = "\n")
  invisible(out)
}
@

\vspace{0.5cm}\\
funExtract function output
\vspace{0.25cm}\\
<< label = lm-usage, echo = FALSE, results = "asis" >>=
funExtract(lm, section="Usage:")
@

\vspace{0.5cm}\\
args function output
\vspace{0.25cm}\\
<< label = lm-args, echo = FALSE, results = "asis" >>=
args(lm)
@


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Issues with funExtract function output**

1. How to get highlighted output from funExtract function as other code?
2. How to remove section title form funExtract function output?

Comment: `args(lm)` should still work in Sweave or knitr.  What are you failing to do?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `formalArgs(lm)`, `formals(lm)` and `sig(lm)`, the last one being in the `sig` package.

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto for showing your willingness to spare time on solving first issue. I'm afraid `out <- out[-1]` is also not providing desired results.

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769). There's a sample Rnw and Rmd file which should work directly if you have the most recent version of "devtools" installed. If not, replace the first few lines with the `helpExtract` function, also at that page. Good luck.

Comment: Fantastic: Thanks @AnandaMahto for sparing your time and writing such nice function. Would to like to change your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer for future users. And also bounty!!

Comment: I have a one-liner solution that I will post later to address all the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had written a function and posted it as an answer earlier (as noted in the question itself), but wasn't entirely happy with the inconsistencies or the requirement that it had to be used with "markdown" to be used successfully. After a little bit more work, this is the function that I came up with:

````
helpExtract <- function(Function, section = "Usage", type = "m_code", ...) {
  A <- deparse(substitute(Function))
  x <- capture.output(tools:::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(help(A, ...)),
                                     options = list(sectionIndent = 0)))
  B <- grep("^_", x)                    ## section start lines
  x <- gsub("_\b", "", x, fixed = TRUE) ## remove "_\b"
  X <- rep(FALSE, length(x))
  X[B] <- 1
  out <- split(x, cumsum(X))
  out <- out[[which(sapply(out, function(x) 
    grepl(section, x[1], fixed = TRUE)))]][-c(1, 2)]
  while(TRUE) {
    out <- out[-length(out)]
    if (out[length(out)] != "") { break }
  } 

  switch(
    type,
    m_code = c("```r", out, "```"),
    s_code = c("<<>>=", out, "@"),
    m_text = paste("    ", out, collapse = "\n"),
    s_text = c("\\begin{verbatim}", out, "\\end{verbatim}"),
    stop("`type` must be either `m_code`, `s_code`, `m_text`, or `s_text`")
  )
}
````

Quite a mouthful, and it's not entirely DRY... but I wanted to capture four scenarios and this was the quickest idea that came to mind. The four scenarios I anticipate are:

1. Document type is markdown and user is extracting a code block (`type = "m_code"`)
2. Document type is markdown and user is extracting a non-code section (`type = "m_text"`)
3. Document type is Sweave and user is extracting a code block (`type = "s_code"`)
4. Document type is Sweave and user is extracting a non-code section (`type = "s_text"`)

The function extracts the output of `Rd2txt`. I picked that over the other formats (HTML, LaTeX) to allow me to use a single function to get what I was after and not have to create multiple functions.

---

#### Usage

Usage is different depending on if you're creating a "Sweave" (.Rnw) or a "markdown" (.Rmd) document.

1. **Markdown**

   Insert your code in a code chunk that looks something like this (maybe one day I'll add different methods, but not now):

   ````
   ```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
   cat(helpExtract(cor), sep = "\n")
   ```
   ````
2. **Sweave**

   Pretend you are inserting a "child" document that should be included in the main document using `Sexpr{knit_child(.)}`

   ```
   \Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(helpExtract(cor, type = "s_code")), 
   options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}
   ```

---

I've [**created a Gist**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769) that includes the function, a sample Rmd file and an sample Rnw file. Feel free to leave comments and suggestions *here on Stack Overflow* (since Gist comments are pretty much meaningless since they don't notify the user when a comment is posted).

---

If you're trying to refer to a function from a package that is not currently loaded, the usage of `helpExtract` should be something like:

```
helpExtract(gls, package = "nlme")
```

Comment: I tested this new function. This works fine with documentclass article but fails with beamer on my machine. Don't why?

Comment: @MYaseen208, I actually don't work with Sweave or Beamer. Please feel free to deconstruct my function and see if you can figure out what works for you.

Comment: @MYaseen208, it works for me. Use the [template here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/beamer/) as a starting point. You'll still probably need to tweak the function if you're using anything other than `type = "s_code"` since the line width of the other sections might not fit on a Beamer slide.

Comment: Needs modifications for functions like `stats::lm`, `nlme::gls`.

Comment: Hello @AnandaMahto: I have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26202078/707145) relating to `helpExtract` function.

Answer (score 6):

I have a function `usage()` in the **formatR** package that captures the arguments of a function. For now, you have to use the [development version](http://yihui.name/formatR/) (>= 0.10.3).

For **knitr**, I also have a recent change (i.e. please also test its development version [on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr)) so that you can the display function usage much more easily: you can use the new chunk option `code` to input code into a chunk.

Put the two pieces together, you will be able to write a code chunk like this:

```
<<test, code=formatR::usage(lm), eval=FALSE>>=
@
```

The reason that these feature came up recently was that I happened to need them by myself as well. I wanted to display the usage of functions with syntax highlighting. This solution is portable to all document formats that **knitr** supports, not limited to Rnw.

Comment: Nice function. Thanks @Yihui for your excellent work. Width of output from this function can be controlled by something like this `formatR::usage(FUN=lm, width=50)`. `helpExtract` function by @AnandaMahto  is more general because it can extract any section of the help file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Rd_db` to get the Rd data from a package.

```
x <- Rd_db("stats")
```

Extract the lm help from this:

```
lmhelp <- x[basename(names(x))=="lm.Rd"]
```

Then use `capture.output` and `Rd2latex` to get latex of the help page:

```
lmhelptex <- capture.output(Rd2latex(lmhelp[[1]]))
```

And pull out the segments you want to include in your rnw file:

```
lmhelptex[do.call(":",as.list(grep("Usage",lmhelptex)))]
[1] "\\begin{Usage}"                                                    
[2] "\\begin{verbatim}"                                                 
[3] "lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action,"                     
[4] "   method = \"qr\", model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE,"
[5] "   singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)"             
[6] "\\end{verbatim}"                                                   
[7] "\\end{Usage}"  

lmhelptex[do.call(":",as.list(grep("Arguments",lmhelptex)))]
 [1] "\\begin{Arguments}"                                                                           
 [2] "\\begin{ldescription}"                                                                        
 [3] "\\item[\\code{formula}] an object of class \\code{\"\\LinkA{formula}{formula}\"} (or one that"
 [4] "can be coerced to that class): a symbolic description of the"                                 
 [5] "model to be fitted.  The details of model specification are given"                            
 [6] "under `Details'."                                                                             
 [7] ""                                                                                             
 [8] "\\item[\\code{data}] ...snip...
```