# knitr chunk option code to input code into a chunk does not work in R 3.1.1 with knitr 1.6.10

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, formatr

I'm using `knitr 1.6.10` in `R 3.1.1`. The chunk option `code` seems like does not work. My MWE in `.Rnw` format is below:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
<< packages, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(formatR)
@

<<test, code=formatR::usage(lm), eval=FALSE>>=
@

\end{document}
```

Previously this function was working ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184629/707145)) but it is not working even-though `formatR::usage(lm)` working outside chunk code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184629/707145) has stated that the **formatR** version must be >= 0.10.3, which is a development version.

```
devtools::install_github('yihui/formatR')
```