# Getting example codes of R functions into knitr using helpExtract function

Tags: r, latex, knitr, noamtools, helpextract

I want to get the example codes of `R` functions to use in `knitr`. There might be an easy way but tried the following code using `helpExtract` function which can be obtained from [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769) (written by @AnandaMahto). With my approach I have to look whether a function has Examples or not and have to include only those functions which have Examples.

This is very inefficient and naive approach. Now I'm trying to include only those functions which have Examples. I tried the following code but it is not working as desired. How can I to extract Examples codes from an `R` package?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

<< label=packages, echo=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7586769")
library(noamtools)     # install_github("noamtools", "noamross")
@


\chapter{Linear Model}

<< label = NewTest1, results="asis">>=
tryCatch(
    {helpExtract(lm, section="Examples", type = "s_text");
    cat(
        "\\Sexpr{
          knit_child(
                  textConnection(helpExtract(lm, section=\"Examples\", type = \"s_text\"))
                , options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = TRUE)
                )
             }", "\n"
        )
     }
  , error=function(e) FALSE
  )
@


\chapter{Modify properties of an element in a theme object}

<< label = NewTest2, results="asis">>=
tryCatch(
    {helpExtract(add_theme , section="Examples", type = "s_text");
    cat(
        "\\Sexpr{
          knit_child(
                  textConnection(helpExtract(add_theme , section=\"Examples\", type = \"s_text\"))
                , options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = TRUE)
                )
             }", "\n"
        )
     }
  , error=function(e) FALSE
  )
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the "chapter" where there are no examples, what do you want to return?

Comment: If there is no Examples, then I would prefer to not have any chapter.

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto for your time, efforts, and help. It would be nice if the output of this function should include the title of section. I would also appreciate if you answer my question. Thanks

Comment: As I look at your example again, I see that you have `eval = TRUE` in there. Would you really want that? What would be the behavior for (for instance) `plot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some quick work modifying the function (which I've included [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3007ab692168f7150021)). The Gist also includes a sample Rnw file (I haven't had a chance to check an Rmd file yet).

The function now looks like this:

````
helpExtract <- function(Function, section = "Usage", type = "m_code", sectionHead = NULL) {
  A <- deparse(substitute(Function))
  x <- capture.output(tools:::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help(A)),
                                     options = list(sectionIndent = 0)))
  B <- grep("^_", x)                      ## section start lines
  x <- gsub("_\b", "", x, fixed = TRUE)   ## remove "_\b"
  X <- rep(FALSE, length(x))              ## Create a FALSE vector
  X[B] <- 1                               ## Initialize
  out <- split(x, cumsum(X))              ## Create a list of sections
  sectionID <- vapply(out, function(x)    ## Identify where the section starts
    grepl(section, x[1], fixed = TRUE), logical(1L))

  if (!any(sectionID)) {                  ## If the section is missing...
    ""                                    ## ... just return an empty character 
  } else {                                ## Else, get that list item
    out <- out[[which(sectionID)]][-c(1, 2)]
    while(TRUE) {                         ## Remove the extra empty lines
      out <- out[-length(out)]            ##   from the end of the file
      if (out[length(out)] != "") { break }
    } 

    switch(                               ## Determine the output type
      type,
      m_code = {
        before <- "```r"
        after <- "```"
        c(sectionHead, before, out, after)
      },
      s_code = {
        before <- "<<eval = FALSE>>="
        after <- "@"
        c(sectionHead, before, out, after)
      },
      m_text = {
        c(sectionHead, paste("    ", out, collapse = "\n"))
      },
      s_text = {
        before <- "\\begin{verbatim}"
        after <- "\\end{verbatim}"
        c(sectionHead, before, out, after)
      },
      stop("`type` must be either `m_code`, `s_code`, `m_text`, or `s_text`")
    )
  }
}
````

---

What has changed?

- A new argument `sectionHead` has been added. This is used to be able to specify the section title in the call to the `helpExtract` function.
- The function checks to see whether the relevant section is available in the parsed document. If it is not, it simply returns a `""` (which doesn't get printed).

---

Example use would be:

```
<<echo = FALSE>>=
mySectionHeading <- "\\section{Some cool section title}"
@

\Sexpr{knit_child(textConnection(
helpExtract(cor, section = "Examples", type = "s_code", 
sectionHead = mySectionHeading)), 
options = list(tidy = FALSE, eval = FALSE))}
```

Note: Since `Sexpr` doesn't allow curly brackets to be used (`{`), we need to specify the title outside of the `Sexpr` step, which I have done in a hidden code chunk.

Comment: (+1): Thanks a lot @AnandaMahto for your help. Only more thing is required, I;m using `help_console` function from `noamtools` package to get the chapter name, `\chapter{\Sexpr{gsub("_\b", "", help_console(topic=lm, format = "text", lines=1), fixed = TRUE)}}`. I wonder how to put optional chapter name if there are Examples for certain function. Thanks

Comment: If I remember original function had option for package. But now the revised function has not this option and this function does not work if  two functions have the same name from two different loaded packages.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer so I'm marking it as community wiki. Here are two simple lines to get the examples out of the Rd file for a named function (in this case `lm`). The code is much simpler than Ananda's gist in my opinion:

```
x <- utils:::.getHelpFile(utils::help(lm))
sapply(x[sapply(x, function(z) attr(z, "Rd_tag") == "\\examples")][[1]], `[[`, 1)
```

The result is a simple vector of all of the text in the Rd "examples" section, which should be easy to parse, evaluate, or include in a knitr doc.

```
 [1] "\n"                                                                          
 [2] "require(graphics)\n"                                                         
 [3] "\n"                                                                          
 [4] "## Annette Dobson (1990) \"An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models\".\n"
 [5] "## Page 9: Plant Weight Data.\n"                                             
 [6] "ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)\n"               
 [7] "trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)\n"               
 [8] "group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c(\"Ctl\",\"Trt\"))\n"                       
 [9] "weight <- c(ctl, trt)\n"                                                     
[10] "lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)\n"                                               
[11] "lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept\n"                     
[12] "\n"                                                                          
[13] "\n"                                                                          
[14] "opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0))\n"                        
[15] "plot(lm.D9, las = 1)      # Residuals, Fitted, ...\n"                        
[16] "par(opar)\n"                                                                 
[17] "\n"                                                                          
[18] "\n"                                                                          
[19] "### less simple examples in \"See Also\" above\n"
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Thomas for your answer. This could be a good start. I wonder how to use your code for `add_theme` function from `ggplot2` package.

Comment: Even with your approach we need to know which functions have Examples and which not. I'm trying to find an automated approach which which include only those functions which have Examples. Any thoughts!!!

Comment: @Thomas, I can't exactly remember *why* I wrote the function the way I did. I believe it was the most straightforward way to get the help file in a manner that could be usable by both markdown and Sweave.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Rd parsing is always a little crazy, I think, so the reasons could have been numerous.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You should be able to use the `attr(z, "Rd_tag") == "\\examples"` statement to determine which Rd files have vignettes. If all of the Rd elements come back FALSE on that comparison, there are no examples.

Comment: @Thomas, I've gone and made things [more complex now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26222019/1270695).... I added some comments to try to show what the general approach was.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following might be useful.

```
get.examples <- function(pkg=NULL) {
  suppressWarnings(f <- unique(utils:::index.search(TRUE, find.package(pkg))))
  out <- setNames(sapply(f, function(x) {
    tf <- tempfile("Rex")
    tools::Rd2ex(utils:::.getHelpFile(x), tf)  
    if (!file.exists(tf)) return(invisible())
    readLines(tf)
  }), basename(f))
  out[!sapply(out, is.null)]
}

ex.base <- get.examples('base')
```

This returns the examples for all functions (that have documentation containing examples) within the specified vector of packages. If `pkg=NULL`, it returns the examples for all functions within loaded packages.

For example:

```
ex.base['scan']
# $scan
#  [1] "### Name: scan"                                                                         
#  [2] "### Title: Read Data Values"                                                            
#  [3] "### Aliases: scan"                                                                      
#  [4] "### Keywords: file connection"                                                          
#  [5] ""                                                                                       
#  [6] "### ** Examples"                                                                        
#  [7] ""                                                                                       
#  [8] "cat(\"TITLE extra line\", \"2 3 5 7\", \"11 13 17\", file = \"ex.data\", sep = \"\\n\")"
#  [9] "pp <- scan(\"ex.data\", skip = 1, quiet = TRUE)"                                        
# [10] "scan(\"ex.data\", skip = 1)"                                                            
# [11] "scan(\"ex.data\", skip = 1, nlines = 1) # only 1 line after the skipped one"            
# [12] "scan(\"ex.data\", what = list(\"\",\"\",\"\")) # flush is F -> read \"7\""              
# [13] "scan(\"ex.data\", what = list(\"\",\"\",\"\"), flush = TRUE)"                           
# [14] "unlink(\"ex.data\") # tidy up"                                                          
# [15] ""                                                                                       
# [16] "## \"inline\" usage"                                                                    
# [17] "scan(text = \"1 2 3\")"                                                                 
# [18] ""                                                                                       
# [19] ""                                                                                       
# [20] ""                                                                                       
# [21] ""
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @jbaums for your answer. Can you explain how to use the output of your function to be use in `knitr` something like `results="asis"`. Thanks